# GPG Permission denied

Tags: permissions, filesystems, gnupg

I just generated a new key and subkey on my mac but when I went to export the keys I got:

```
$ gpg --export-secret-keys --armor keyid > privkey.asc
-bash: privkey.asc: Permission denied
```

How do I fix the permissions, or manually view the ~/.gnupg directory?

Answer (score -3):

To view the permissions:

```
$ ls -l privkey.asc
(displays permissions for this file, if it is in the current directory)
$ ls -ld ~/.gnupg
(displays permissions for this directory)
$ ls -l ~/.gnupg/*
(displays permissions for the files in this directory)
```

The permissions depend on the user and on the permissions granted to the user. This is pretty basic *nix shell material.

Comment: My problem presented with an error message of "update failed permission denied" when working within the gpg tool's edit system and running a save command but this answer led me to a fix.  My permissions allowed me to read and write the file but it turned out that one of the files had become owned by root:root rather than me.  Adding a hit that chmod or chown may be needed to fix anything that does not allow write access by the user would improve this answer.